# How can I sort (rank) the elements of an array, according to another array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, ranking

I have to arrays in my C# project whose elements with the same index have a relationship:

The simplified example is as follows:

```
Array_1 [0] =902;
Array_1 [1] =109;
Array_1 [2] =205;
Array_1 [3] =187;
Array_1 [4] =440;
Array_1 [5] =508;


Array_2 [0] ="Ford";
Array_2 [1] ="Opel";
Array_2 [2] ="Kia";
Array_2 [3] ="Renault";
Array_2 [4] ="BMW";
Array_2 [5] ="Toyota";
```

I have to sort Array-2 according to the value ranking of Array_1(low to High). The result will be written into Array_2_sorted. That means:
Array_1's lowest value is Array_1[1] (109) --> so Array_2[1] (Opel) should be Array_2_sorted[0]

the next higher value is Array_1[3] (187) --> so Array_2[3] (Renault) should be Array_2_sorted[1]

the next higher value is Array_1[2] (205) --> so Array_2[2] (Kia) should be Array_2_sorted[2]

the next higher value is Array_1[4] (440) --> so Array_2[4] (BMW) should be Array_2_sorted[3]

...

How can I do such a sorting (ranking) of an array in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.Sort` offers such functionality.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-7.0#system-array-sort(system-array-system-array)

> Sorts a pair of one-dimensional Array objects (one contains the keys and the other contains the corresponding items) based on the keys in the first Array using the IComparable implementation of each key.

So simply call

```
Array.Sort(Array_1, Array_2);
```

See here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/mKIM7o

Comment: Huh, you learn something new every day... Nice!

Comment: @Rand Random Works fine but have one problem. If all the array ellements are filled then it works. But due to my use case, somethimes the array is not filled completely. I mean both arrays Arr1,Arr2 have 100 fields but just 85 filled. In this case the empty elements cause to faulty ordering.

Comment: @Mdarende - you should create a new question for this, and please provide sample data for the described issue makes it easier (input - expected output vs actual output)

Answer (score 2):

[removed first snippet because it didn't work]

Update:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] Array_1 = { 902, 109, 205, 187, 440, 508 };
        string[] Array_2 = { "Ford", "Opel", "Kia", "Renault", "BMW", "Toyota" };

        var combinedArray = Enumerable.Range(0, Array_1.Length)
            .Select(i => new { Value = Array_1[i], Car = Array_2[i] })
            .ToArray();

        combinedArray = combinedArray.OrderBy(item => item.Value).ToArray();

        int[] Array_1_sorted = combinedArray.Select(item => item.Value).ToArray();
        string[] Array_2_sorted = combinedArray.Select(item => item.Car).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Array_1_sorted:");
        foreach (int value in Array_1_sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nArray_2_sorted:");
        foreach (string car in Array_2_sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(car);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This involves a lot of inefficient searching through the arrays, doesn't handle the same car appearing twice, and [throws an exception](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoagSzwwG0BdAAgEEooBDATwH0yrALysA3qwCcABhJpWZaZPklpAVnlkAHAHZ5KFNPlrpW1gF8A3NSKKWHLn34kR41gCIAYtAAm7+e4A8gAOMAA2/h4A0rTcke4ASjB43DhhGPEAQgCyAOrxACoQvBAYcRbWNFScPLwAdADK0BgAFDVOcqwtCPK8AJQiAHzUYtSs46z0GJN4PjAIABqu7fUAkrPzgQBmbY4CnQh9lRMz0/RzCACay3t16xfbu7XOvUdjE0Q6Ds9kjOfzC2YdQAwhAALbBbiwIpPJy/f5XZhvKjmZE2OxsFbOfgAZ2aMB8N2eJEsQA=)

Comment: ah yes sorry, i updated it.

Comment: (The first snippet still doesn't work). Now, you can use `.Zip` instead of the `Enumerable.Range` + `Select`, and use a ValueTuple instead of an anonymous object to reduce allocations, and you'll arrive at my answer

Comment: oh wow, Rand Random wins I think.

Comment: @AndrewArrow - was there ever doubt that I would win? :D

Comment: who was that Rand Random? He's like Zorro! Just needs to slash an "RR" and ride off into the sunset.

Answer (score 2):

A simple linq-y way:

```
var Array_2_sorted = 
    Array_1.Zip(Array_2, ((rank, car) => (rank, car))
    .OrderBy(x => x.rank)
    .Select(x => x.car);
```

First, we take both arrays, and we match them up element for element. The rank (from Array_1) becomes the `rank` member, and the make (from Array_2) becomes the `car` member. The easiest way to do this is using linq's [`.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1)))).

```
[0]: (rank: 902, car: "Ford")
[1]: (rank: 109, car: "Opel")
...
```

Then, we simply order by the `rank` members, ascending, using linq's [`.OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-7.0). That gives us:

```
[0]: (rank: 109, car: "Opel")
[1]: (rank: 187, car: "Renault")
...
```

Then we just select the `car` members, and drop the `rank` members:

```
[0]: "Opel"
[1]: "Renault"
...
```

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAGAAiIEYA6AGQEs8BHAbgFgAoTxjAbQF0yAQShQAhgE8A+pTIBeMnhgB3MjwFkA3gE4SAJjRlKJbYb0kArIcoAOAOyGUKEoYskbZAL7suvqiQ0RcWk9eUUVCmMNTTIAIgAxaAATWMNYgHkABxgAG1S4gGl6MXzYgCUYPDEcHIxSgCEAWQB1UoAVCAkIDBLvTk4ANzEoYVFJKT0pAGdoDBgksM4yZdHgmWoALXpMgAog8YMyHfE8AGtDMGGASnkAPiOT87JLqCurpZXqdKgkmCh6iQ7BB3MgIaiPd4cFZkagAZVyMDAGCBILBLyuPk4+xC01m82oHWxOyu1AAIjgALa7DFAA==).